# what does "when all's said and done" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does "when all's said and done" mean?

Does it have different meanings depending on the situation?

First Guess: it means "most importantly":

> "When all's said and done, charity begins at home".

Second Guess: it means "on balance":

> "When all's said and done, it is kind of a necessary evil".

Third Guess: it means "you know":

> Person A: I don’t have enough cash on hand to pay the bills!
>
> Person B: Not again! When all’s said and done, I think you’ll have to ask your mom for a loan.

Are my guesses correct on what it would mean?

Comment: It means what is says:  After everything about the topic has been said and done.

Comment: What @HotLicks said. It means exactly what it says: after everything relevant has been said about X, and everything relevant has been done about X, ... Something close to it would be: after everything about X has been taken into consideration,...

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the context, when used correctly, it [means](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/when+all+is+said+and+done) **ultimately** or **when everything is taken into consideration**, and it is usually followed by an important or decisive statement.

**Example:**

> It's a generous offer, but when all is said and done, I have to choose the job that will be most beneficial for my family.

Comment: Yes. There are alternative idioms which serve a similar purpose - e.g. "At the end of the day..."

Comment: +1. I agree, i was going to add 'At the end of the day' but i didn't want to potentially add any confusion since both can be used in the same sentence.

Comment: It might also be helpful to let the OP know that their second guess is correct "when everything is taken into consideration" = "on balance".

Comment: "In the final analysis" is another.